# Why is my setuid function not working?

Tags: c, cygwin, posix

I've the following simple code to check my getuid function:

```
            uidActual=getuid(); 

            printf ("User id is [%d]\n", uidActual);                            

            error=setuid(197623);
            printf("[%d]",error);

            uidActual=getuid();
            printf ("\n User id is [%d]\n", uidActual);
```

But it always returns a -1 as error, so the uid doesn't change.

The 197623 in setuid seems right as I've, apart from other things, the following in my mkpasswd command:

user1: 197609:197609[...]

user2: 197623:197121[...]

Where 197609 and 197623 must be the id for the user as in fact I start the application with user 1 and I obtain its id properly displaying at the beginning and the end: "User id is 197609".

I've set all permissions for everyone on the created executable and I've even run the executable as a root in cygwin with cygstart --action=runas ./a.exe and it still doesn't work.

Funny thing is that the setgid (for changing group) function works perfectly with setgid(197121), even without special permissions or running. So I'm out of ideas of why this function always returns an error.

Any idea on what is wrong on my code that could be causing the problem?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: So what's the error? The return value of -1 tells you there *was* an error; the error is stored in `errno` and you can get a description with `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: Didn't know about errno, it says operation not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code must be run by a user with appropriate privileges. Perhaps by:

```
sudo ./a.exe
```

here is an excerpt from the (linux) man page for setuid()

"EPERM  The  user is not privileged (Linux: does not have the CAP_SETUID  capability) and uid does not match the real UID  or  saved  set-user-ID of the calling process."